# XSLT : Return true if child exists in a specified path

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I check if a node is exists in a specified path? 
For example, I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <bookgroup name="group1">
    <book name="BookName1"/>
    <book name="BookName2"/>
    <book name="BookName3"/>
    <book name="BookName4"/>
    <book name="BookName5"/>
  </bookgroup>
  <bookgroup name="group2">
    <book name="BookName6"/>
    <book name="BookName7"/>
  </bookgroup>
  <selected>
    <book name="BookName2"/>
    <book name="BookName3"/>
  </selected>
</books>
```

The desire output is to return true for  since the child node : BookName2 and BookName 3 are exists in the selected tag and false for  because none of its child is in the selected tag.

This is what I have tried:

```
    <xsl:template name="IsChildExist">
    <xsl:param name="bookGroupName"/>
    <xsl:variable name="isExist">
        <xsl:for-each select="//bookgoup[@NAME=$bookGroupName]/book">
            <xsl:variable name="childNode" select="./@name"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="count(//selected/book[@name=$childNode])>0">
                    <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$isExist"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But still fighting on the break in a for-each loop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Anders Lindahl, I have try creating a template and looping through the child nodes and check against the selected nodes but got stack on figuring out how to break the loop :(

Comment: Show the code, and the desired output - it isn't entirely clear what kind of result you want from the transformation.

Comment: @Anders Lindahl, added what i have tried in the problem, hope this helps

Comment: sprenna, consider to post the output you want to create with XSLT for the input sample you have posted, then we can suggest an XSLT way of doing this.

Comment: The desired output is TRUE for bookgroup1 and FALSE for bookgroup2 as the result when calling the template.

Comment: sprenna, What shold be the result if a `bookgroup` has only one (and not two) `book` with `name` attribute equal to the `name` attributes of `selected/book` -- `true()` or `false()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSLT has no concept of 'breaking' out of a loop. It is a functional language and so you need to change your mind set away from normal flow of control in imperative languages.

To solve your particular problem, you could make use of a key to look up the selected books

```
<xsl:key name="selected" match="selected/book" use="@name" />
```

You don't actually need the **xsl:for-each** at all. You can look up to select if any of a list of elements belong in a key, not just a specific element

```
<xsl:template name="IsChildExist">
  <xsl:param name="bookGroupName" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:variable name="isExist">
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="key('selected', //bookgroup[@name=$bookGroupName]/book/@name)">
           <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$isExist"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, do you need to use a named template at all? Depending on what you are trying to output, you could just do this making use of normal tempate pattern matching in XSLT. Try this XSL

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="selected" match="selected/book" use="@name" />

   <xsl:template match="bookgroup[key('selected', book/@name)]">
      <bookgroup>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:text>TRUE</xsl:text>
      </bookgroup>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="bookgroup">
      <bookgroup>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
         <xsl:text>FALSE</xsl:text>
      </bookgroup>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="selected" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<books>
   <bookgroup name="group1">TRUE</bookgroup>
   <bookgroup name="group2">FALSE</bookgroup>
</books>
```